# How to get Anchor tag (which works with JS function call) to work using rightClick > open in new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I'm using an anchor tag

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascriptMethod();">asdasdasd</a>
```

This javascript function dynamically decides on the page to open. Works all right on click.
But when I right click and Open in new tab, it just shows me a blankie!!

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this:

**jQUERY**

```
$(function(){

    $('a').mousedown(function(e){

         // On mouse down check to see if it was left, middle or right click

         switch (e.which) {

            case 1: // Left Mouse CLick

                // Prevent click event on link

                e.preventDefault(); 

                // Redirect to where javascriptMethod() says

                location.href = javascriptMethod(); 

            break;

            case 2: // Middle Mouse CLick

                // Prevent click event on link

                e.preventDefault(); 

                // Redirect to where javascriptMethod() says

                location.href = javascriptMethod(); 

            break;

            case 3: // Right Mouse CLick

                // On right mouse click change the href attribute of the link.

                // This way the 'Open link in new tab' and 'Open link in new window' 

                // will use the right link

                $(this).prop('href', javascriptMethod());

            break;
        }

    });

    // Here you will decide which link to return. I just hard coded  Google

    function javascriptMethod() {

        return 'http://www.google.com';
    }

})
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume your javascript function will mimic the `<a>` natural behavior of `navigation`. I suggest using other HTML tags like `<div>`, `<span>` etc. By doing so, will prevent the browser from showing the "Open in new tab" option in the context menu.

@tliokos's answer might work but i think it will confuse users and change the behavior of click events, especially on using `mousedown()`, if you noticed, your browser usually starts navigating only on mouseup instead, etc..